# Why is it "Discipulus pulcher est" and not "Discipulus pulchrus est"?

Tags: morphology, declension, adjective, gender

I think its something with declension, but can't quite wrap my head around why it would be pulcher instead of pulchrus for that phrase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no word *pulchrus*. The word in the masculine, nominative, singular is *pulcher*, and it is one of the 2nd declension noun and adjectives that end in -er.

There are many adjectives of this type, and some of the most common include: *aeger* (sick), *ater* (bad, unlucky, dark), *dexter* (right, like right-handed), *integer* (complete, intact), *macer* (skinny), *niger* (black), *piger* (sluggish), *ruber* (red), *sacer* (holy), and *sinister* (left).

For these words, the only place you see the -er is with the masculine singular nominative/vocative. For the rest, the -er is dropped and the root is formed with just the -r-; so you'll have *aeger*, *aegri*, *aegro*, *aegrum*, *aegrae*, *aegrae*, etc.

(There are some exceptions. Some writers kept the -e- in *dexter*, though it's not as common, and you'll also find *sinisterior* in the comparative.)

You also have a whole class of words ending in -fer or -ger, like *belliger*, *bifer*, *dulcifer*, and *somnifer*, as well as a few others, like *asper* (rough), *lacer* (mutilated, mangled), *liber* (free), *miser* (poor), and *tener* (soft), for which the -er remains throughout; so *belliger*, *belligeri*, *belligero*, *belligera*, etc.

There are also a handful of nouns that fall under this pattern, with the most common being *ager* (gen. *agri*) and *puer* (gen. *pueri*).

Comment: Note: Asper, lacer, tener, liber and miser always keep the -e-.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Thanks, I added them in.